# WebClient - asynchronous download and request timed out with Mono

Tags: mono, webclient, threadpool

I am using System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileAsync() method to download a file from internet to the local drive. In Windows environment, there is no problem but when I try with Mono, "request timed out" message appears as soon as download starts and the download operation fails (zero-byte file).

I've found some articles on the internet including [1] and [2] that says the problem is related to ThreadPool and setting MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000 would be resolution. So far, I've tried:

1. In Win CMD prompt, SET MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000: not resolved
2. In Mono 2.10.8 CMD prompt, SET MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000 not resolved
3. By using mono-tools [3] via Visual Studio, created a profile as MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000 (in environmental variables setting): not resolved

Related Links:

1. http://www.mono-project.com/Article:ThreadPool_Deadlocks
2. http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono
3. -http://mono-tools.com/Debug.aspx

Operating System: Win7 x64, Mono Version: 2.10.8

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFile(url, temp);
```

Comment: Why do you need Mono on Windows?

Comment: You may also want to use a tool like fiddler to check if the connection is being requested.

Comment: The threadpool issue you linked to only relates to Mono versions <=2.6.x so i wouldn't expect what you've tried to make any impact.

Comment: @knocte Trying to develop a cross-platform application ^^

Comment: @ThomasJames about fiddler, I guess you mean the connection is requested at Mono side? I'm not sure how it's related, cause the connection is OK at Windows machine. on the other hand, mono could not resolve this problem or I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Mono for Windows is not needed to develop a cross-platform application, you simply can use .NET in Windows and Mono on Linux/Mac